# How to run already installed iOS app through Xcode without rebuilding it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm experiencing a strange problem where there are differences between Debug and Release builds.

When I make build via Xcode (in Debug or even in Release configuration; on device even on simulator) everything works fine.
But when I install build from AppStore, AppCenter or TestFlight (hereinafter Stores) there is issue with one of my functions

I think that the bug itself isn’t what’s important here. But maybe not...

Problem occurs with function formatting Double.

```swift
private lazy var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    let fractionDigits: Int = 2
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
    formatter.locale = self.locale // `self.locale` returns current Locale
    formatter.numberStyle = .none
    return formatter
}()

func formattedAmount(_ value: Double) -> String {
    let number = NSNumber(value: value)
    return numberFormatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
}
```

**In case when application runs from Xcode I’m getting correctly formatted String**

```swift
let amount: Double = 324.44
let string = formattedAmount(amount)
print(string) //prints 324,44 (or with dot according to Locale) -> everything is alright
```

**In case when application is installed from Stores**

```swift
let amount: Double = 324.44
let string = formattedAmount(amount)
print(string) //prints 200103300
```

in this case `string` is equal to to some garbage. It’s always number 9 or 10 char long, sometimes with minus (e.g `200103300` or `-126776678`)

Is there a way to run build already installed on iPhone through Xcode, without rebuilding it, so that I can debug my code?
Or is something wrong with project settings, that can affect how code works when app is deployed to Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run build already installed on iPhone through Xcode, without rebuilding it, so that I can debug my code?

Yes. You can do a <kbd>Run Without Building</kbd> like this:

[image: Run Without Building]

You could also just run the app normally (click it on the home screen), then attach the process.

[image: Attach to Process]

> in this case string is equal to to some garbage. It’s always number 9 or 10 char long, sometimes with minus (e.g 200103300 or -126776678)

Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Unfortunately `Run Without Building` does not work for me. It seems that it reinstalls app (even in Xcode there is indicator that says so -> `Installing to...`). This does not allow me to replicate my problem.

Attaching proccess leads to error -> attach by pid '1708' failed. I am currently investigating this issue further and will edit my answer later if there is some progress.